# Using package 255kb/meteor-status Nothing appears on my application when I call the template {{> meteorStatus}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, connection

I created a simple Hello World Meteor example and was trying to use the meteor-status package. In GitHub the [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/255kb/meteor-status) says to use the template `{ {> meteorStatus} }` but when running the application, the screen goes blank, if I remove `{{> meteorStatus}}` the application shown normally

Answer (score 0):

Are those extra spaces in your { {> meteorStatus} } in your application?  If so, that's probably your issue and you should use {{> meteorStatus}} without spaces.

Comment: Sorry there is no extra spaces, I did not realize that when I wrote had been spaces. I Could not find a solution yet, but seeing the Todos example i could make my application displays a warning when it loses connection with the server.

Comment: Excuse my english, im still learning. 
Im new with Meteor, actually im working with a web application and the new task is to make it run on Android and iOS, for this it would be good to see a warning if the connection with the server has been lost